# Creating a subdomain through vhost or htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, vhosts

Currently working on a project on my local xampp setup. I am using a test domain like so: testsite.devs. Now, I want to create an admin interface using the subdomain admin.testsite.devs. I have it working, but Im currently using vhost like so:

```
    <VirtualHost testsite.devs:443>
     DocumentRoot "D:/websites/testsite"
     ServerName testsite.devs
     ServerAlias testsite.devs
     ErrorLog "logs/testsite.devs-error.log"
     CustomLog "logs/testsite.devs-access.log" combined
     <Directory "D:/websites/testsite">
        Require all granted    
     </Directory>
     SetEnv ENVTYPE "dev"
     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile "crt/testsite.devs/server.crt"
     SSLCertificateKeyFile "crt/testsite.devs/server.key"
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost admin.testsite.devs:443>
     DocumentRoot "D:/websites/testsite/admin"
     ServerName admin.testsite.devs
     ServerAlias admin.testsite.devs
     ErrorLog "logs/admin.testsite.devs-error.log"
     CustomLog "logs/admin.testsite.devs-access.log" combined
     <Directory "D:/websites/testsite/admin">
        Require all granted    
     </Directory>
     SetEnv ENVTYPE "dev"
     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile "crt/testsite.devs/server.crt"
     SSLCertificateKeyFile "crt/testsite.devs/server.key"
 </VirtualHost>
```

It appears to work, but Im thinking if I dont have access to a vhost file, is there a easier way to just do this via the htaccess file? I tried examples found online like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.testsite.devs
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ testsite.devs/admin/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

But if I go to:

admin.testsite.devs/index.html

The URL changes to:

testsite.devs/admin/index.html

So using htaccess, how do I create the sub domain where the URL stays the same? So if I go to admin.testsite.devs/index.html, it stays that way in the URL bar?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /admin/$1 [END]`

Comment: Do not use arbitrary TLDs, you will only get problems. Create a domain name, in whatever TLD, and then use it as suffix for all your names.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek Can you give me an example? As Im not sure what you are talking about. Sorry for being slow.

Comment: If you create a domain `example.com` (not that one obviously but a real one that you register for real through a specific registrar and registry), then use it for all your needs: `testsite.example.com`, `admin.testsite.example.com`, etc.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek But I thought that is what I was doing. Are you saying I should just use one vhost entry for the domain instead of breaking it out into 2? If so, then what do I need to put into my htaccess file to tell it the root directory for admin.example.com is a different subdirectory? I dont want admin.example.com to go to the root, I want it to go to a different sub directory.

Comment: Your question used `.devs` which is not a real TLD. OR it is bad obfuscation, I do not know. So it is hard to understand.

Comment: "I dont want admin.example.com to go to the root, I want it to go to a different sub directory." Then point your `DocumentRoot` at two completely separate directories. For now, one is a subdirectory of the other, that is probably your main problem. Like `DocumentRoot "D:/websites/testsite/main"` and `DocumentRoot "D:/websites/testsite/admin"`. Adjust content on disk obviously.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek Yeah I usually use .dev for local sites and use the host file to resolve the domain to localhost. But I can no longer use .dev because its a built in extension google uses. So .devs is now recommended, in fact .dev is a common extension used for local testing. I thought you meant something else, thats why I was confused. Changing the TLD wont change the issue Im having. Your last comment about sub directories, I already do that.

Comment: "So .devs is now recommended" CErtainly NOT. Do not use any abritrary TLD out of your imagination, you are only creating problems for yourself. Either use the TLDs put aside specifically for documentation, like `.test` or `.example`. OR use a real domain that you register through a registrar in whatever TLD you wish and then use that domain as suffix of all your names. Again, DO NOT use any arbitrary TLDs. The idea looks nice but comes with a lot of downsides you will see only later and when it is time to rename everything you will be sad.

Comment: "in fact .dev is a common extension used for local testing. ".  No, it is a common **error** to have used it. See https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/. The fact that many people do the same error does not suddenly change the error into a good practice.

Comment: "Your last comment about sub directories, I already do that." this is certainly not reflected in your post since you have there `DocumentRoot "D:/websites/testsite"` and `DocumentRoot "D:/websites/testsite/admin"` clearly they are not separate directories, the second one is a subdirectory of the first one...